# Category blog - 8 column layout

Tags: joomla-4.x, css, category-blog, html

I have a fresh install of Cassiopeia/Joomla 4 and I am trying to give the Category blog 8 columns. When I add that number under Blog Layout it reverts to 1 column? Values 1-4 seem to work. But anything above 4 columns doesnt? Seems like a design flaw to me. How can I override this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://slides.woluweb.be/cassiopeia/cassiopeia.html "Joomla 4 – Cassiopeia Template – a bunch of Tips & Tricks" by Marc Dechèvre. This article can help you.

Comment: This post doesn't yet meet the Stack Exchange guidelines for an "answer". Please explicitly write the actual resolving advice into this post.  Offering a link to a complete resource can be helpful, but an answer must do more than simply reroute web traffic.  Please pull the necessary insights from that offsite webpage so that even if that page url moves or is deleted, this answer will be timelessly helpful.  If left unedited, this answer may be converted to a comment under the question -- but it would be better to improve this post.